# How to get JWT_TOKEN through /api/auth/login in Thingsboard?

Tags: thingsboard

When I tried to get telemetry time series data through *Data Query API*, I need `JWT_TOKEN`. I followed the [documentation](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/rest-api/#rest-api-auth) and applied:

`get_token.sh`:

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d '{"username":"tenant@thingsboard.org", "password":"tenant"}' 'http://THINGSBOARD_URL/api/auth/login'
```

I need to apply `api/auth/login`. But I can't find it in my installation of *thingsboard (CE)* and *dem0.thingsboard.io*.

Can someone let me know if `api/auth/login` is supported in CE or PE?

Answer (score 0):

can you please clarify your question. What is the error? Your command should return two tokens, and you should use the first one. This should be included in the header section for your request.

```
 token = requests.post('http://demo.thingsboard.io/api/auth/login',
                              json=token_json, headers=token_header).json()["token"]
```

That line should give you the token you need for other operations or request that need to be done.